# Xamarin android google map

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, installation

I want to use Google map in my application but I have problems to use it.

If you need use google map on Xamarin, you need install the component google map but with the component the application can't work with a lot of problems.

You can see a lot of persons have this problems when you install this :

http://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices/

Someone Has an idea to use the Api Google on the application and not a web view ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The play services component is broken, has been for months, you can
1, use osmdroid
2, download the nuget packages individually,

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link.

[Xamarin Android Google Maps](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-google-map-with-marker/)

Getting your app working with Google Maps is pretty easy. However the map will not render in a simulator unless you can get a simulator that is running google play services etc. But the map will run and be fully functional on an actual device.